# Como abrir um URL direto da notificação

Tags: android, android-notification

Quero ciar um aplicativo para abrir URLs que se redirecionam para a Play Store e quero que apenas carregue o URL direto na notificação sem abir nenhum layout, e que apareça no filtro de intenção do android, Ex: (Concluir esta ação utilizando: Chrome, Navegador, Redirect Browser).Mas não sei como fazê-lo. Comecei criar o codigo:

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        public void alerta (View v) {

        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this);
        notification.setContentTitle("Carregando página da Web...");
        notification.setContentText("A Play Store se abrira ao concluir");
        notification.setSmallIcon((R.drawable.ic_launcherrb));
        notification.setSound(Uri.parse("/system/media/audio/notifications/Argon.ogg"));


        notification.build();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());

}}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar??

Answer (score 4):

Deve criar um *PendingIntent* da seguinte forma:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(A_Sua_URL));
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

e adicioná-lo à notificação assim:

```
notification.setContentIntent(pIntent);
```